# How can I achieve high efficiency in a SEPIC with AC inductor losses? Where's all my energy going and why?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, sepic

I'm building an asynchronous SEPIC converter with a wide input range (10-60 V) and a 24 V 2 A output. This is based on an LM5022, and I'm trying to achieve high efficiency as its heat generation is a big consideration for this design.

In the design, I've selected efficient components such as a 4.5 mΩ 57 nC MOSFET, a Schottky rectifier with a 300 mV drop and a reasonably oversized, very low DCR (45 mΩ) coupled inductor, but I'm not able to achieve efficiency over 84% despite calculations yielding >90%.

I've been calculating for switching losses (gate and DC losses,) DCR losses in the inductor, diode and current sense resistor.  From thermal imagery it appears as if the majority of the loss is coming from the inductor. I've been at wit's end trying to determine how to calculate and alter inductive losses that obviously exceed the DCR of 45 mΩ. All calculations and methods I've found referencing AC losses refer to inductor ACR and core losses (flux density, exponents, material constants) which don't exist in my inductor datasheets (MSD1514-153MED).

Where's all this heat coming from, and how do I make it stop?

The design is attached for reference if it's helpful. I'm observing a little ripple on the FET and am currently assuming the layout and HF loop are adequate. Switching at 500 kHz.

[image]

Comment: _”Where's all this heat coming from”_ An IR camera is ideal tool to find out. A poor man’s version of it would be to put the board in the freezer, take it out quickly once it has iced up and turn it on. The part which the ice melts first is the one dissipated the most power (save for large heatsinks which may obscure results).

Comment: Oh, as described in the question, I've used an IR/thermal camera and can see it's in the inductor. My question is, how? Or perhaps, how does one calculate core and Pacr losses perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Somewhat simplified: Flux swing times frequency heats the core. Current squared heats the wire. Get yourself a better inductor? Challenge the topology choice and consider buck-boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *So my question: Where's all this heat coming from, and how do I make
> it stop!?*

The inductor you have chosen as 24 mΩ DC resistance (**per winding**) and this is nearly 5 times worse than the on-resistance of the MOSFET you have used so, it's bound to be the weakest link regarding heat generation. I did say "per winding" (note 3 in data sheet) so, realistically, it's a very poor choice.

Also, if you read the data sheet you'll see that with an RMS current of 3.4 amps flowing through both windings, the inductor's temperature will rise 40° C above ambient (note 6 on page 2 of the [data sheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/597/msd1514-1076568.pdf)) so, it's going to be maybe 15° C warmer than ambient in your circumstances.

The inductor you have chosen seems to be the weakest link regarding power efficiency. My recommendation is to choose a better coupled inductor with much lower DC resistance in the windings (comparable with the MOSFET on-resistance).

Notes 3 and 6 on data sheet: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Sadly, this inductor seems to be one of, if not, the best-coupled inductors I could find, and I'm quickly approaching a reality in which this may need to be separate inductors. How do core losses play into this as well?

Further, is DCR on the windings measurable with a simple DMM?

Comment: Core losses are hard to judge but, from the look of it, they should be OK. I'd use a 1 amp power supply and a voltmeter to measure the dc resistance @AlexTurner <-- it's only redeeming parameter is the leakage inductance but, given that the sepic circuit will couple leakage energy to the secondary, I don't see it as a big deal-breaker if coupling were more like 0.98.

Comment: @AlexTurner Consider getting an EI or EM core and winding your own inductor. Flyback transformers may also be suitable coupled inductors.

Comment: @AlexTurner If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.